# How to get cell background color using google sheet rest api?

Tags: google-sheets-api

There are options to apply color but not to get what color is applied. There is no link available in documentation provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) api. Response of this api will be in [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets) format. You can traverse it up to [cell](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells)  where you can find CellFormat.

Comment: Thanks Manthan, I got the data from your links provided.

Comment: @ParikshitPatil If this answer solve you question, then can you select this answer, so this can be useful to other too.